# Simple question about int

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok.... This seems like a simple question but I can't find any info about it so I thought I would ask here.

I am trying to store a number (int) in a var but I need to keep the 0's before it

eg:

```
int x = 0001;
NSLog(@"%i",x)  // returns 1
```

Is it possible to make it return 0001?

I know that i can do this:

```
NSLog(@"%04i",x);  // returns 0001
```

But that is not quite the answer i am looking for because the number of 0's needs to vary.

I don't specifically need to use an int but it would need to be a whole number.

Comment: In C, a numeric constant starting with `0` is interpreted as octal. If you need a specific format, either use a real integer and pad it when you output it, or use a string.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?  How are you planning on using this integer with leading zeros?  There's probably a better way of achieving your goal, but we need to know more.

Comment: Why doesn't `%04i` work the way you want it to? It should ensure that the number is four digits long, padded with leading zeros. Also, watch out for that octal thing that Wooble mentioned, it'll bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the string, rather than the value, you need to use a string variable.

```
NSString *x = @"0001";
NSLog(@"%@",x);
```

Then when you need to do some calculations, use "[x intValue]".

Comment: @Flyingdiver Of course save it as a string.... i know it would be a simple one like that. My brain is a bit fried at the moment. Thanks Flyingdiver this is the answer I needed.

Comment: @Blindy: not if the number of 0s is, for some horrible reason, really an essential part of the data the OP is representing.

Comment: @Blindy I know where you are coming from but in this example it is really only being used to create a string. At most, I need to increase the number by 1 so I think this will work for now.

Comment: @Blindy - it's clear from the question that the content and format of the string is more important than how the integer value is stored, so I don't see what's wrong with using a string.

Answer (score 6):

The leading 0's are insignificant, and adding them will [make the number an octal literal](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html), so you can not log them with out specifying the width. You can however specify a dynamic width to print.

```
int dyn_width = 4;
int x = 1;

NSLog(@"%0*i", dyn_width, x);
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer, didn't know you could do that! I was actually thinking of `sprintf`ing a format string for another `printf` function (or the obj-c equivalents).

Comment: @Joe i like this idea. I didn't realise that you could do this. This was kind of how I was thinking that it would work but I just couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: Here you go http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html search for "field width" and you will see the `*` explained.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using a string, which you don't want, the only way I can see to code the number of 0s before the first significant digit is to store the value in a `double`, as `0.0001`. Of course in some cases, precision might be an issue, not mentioning that arithmetic on that style of integer representations becomes more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the number of zeroes you're trying to display is not part of your model (the actual backing store, the `int`), but of the presentation (so a function taking your `int` and displaying it somehow).

Regardless, elementary math teaches us that `1` is the same number as `01`, so you'll have a hard time convincing the computer any differently.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question, does it?

Comment: Considering your answer, no, I don't believe you'd understand *how* it answers it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options - create an object that both holds the int-value (1) the padding-count (3) and the padding type (zeros), or use a string.  Using a string can cause other problems later (validation, can you stop other parts of the code putting string data like text in there?)

But, the real question is, why do you want this.. surely there's another way?  Code refactor time!